# print a matrix without the first line and first column

Tags: r, matrix, row

I want to print a matrix (*.txt) without the first line and the first column.

Thanks in advance!

```
X  <- read.table("tmp02.txt")    
x1 <- matrix(x)    
P  <- matrix(0, nrow(x), ncol(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
as.matrix(read.table("tmp02.txt",skip=1)[-1])
```